# JavaFX connecting components to model

Tags: java, binding, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX user interface with several controls; the values should be stored inside fields of a Model class; the UI class has a reference to Model.

Say the Model class is the basic:

```
public static class Model{String myText; /*javabeans getters and setters provided too*/}
```

The JavaFX Application is the following.

```
public class T08 extends Application {

Model model;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    model = new Model();

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bp));

    //this is the component that should be connected to model.myText
    TextField textField = new TextField();

    bp.setCenter(textField);        
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

#### Question

1. The user can write text in textField control and the text should be saved into model.myText.
2. During application startup i need to load the data into the Model and have it rendered to the controls.

   I've tried with JavaFX 2.x bindings, but they seem to focus on unidirectional connections. 
   What are my options to accomplish this in a neat way?

Comment: Please show what you have tried with bindings.

Comment: @Puce: it seems not to be the right way to do this, however it was adding the javafx-2 "property" to Model class, that is: 1) converting myText from String to SimpleTextProperty myTextProperty; 2) adding the prperty accessor: public StringProperty myTextProperty() {return myTextProperty;}
3) bind the datamodel to the textField: model.myTextProperty().bind(textField.textProperty()); So,UI values get replicated to model, but model values cannot be set because of RuntimeException "A bound value cannot be set".Moreover values loaded into model at startup get lost when it got bound to the controls.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `myTextProperty.bindBidirectional()` instead of `myTextProperty.bind()`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I wrote some SSCCE sample code, since code explains the things more precisely :)

First example is for this question:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication10 extends Application {

    private Model model = new Model();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setText(model.getMyText());

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Done");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                model.setMyText(textField.getText());
                System.out.println("Done.");
                System.out.println("New value: " + model.getMyText());
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(textField);
        root.setBottom(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // Data Model
    public static class Model {
        private String myText = "model myText default";

        public String getMyText() {
            return myText;
        }

        public void setMyText(String myText) {
            this.myText = myText;
        }
    }
}
```

The second modified version (uses bidirectional binding) of this example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340766/682495).
In both examples try to click the button.

Comment: can you split the two anwers and post the one relative to my previous question to that thread, so that i can accept it? About this question, yours is just an event based synchronization, and it is unidirectional too, just like the one i did! the bidi is done by the line textField.setText(model.getMyText()); that is: you access the model through the controls. here i was answering: what OTHER solutions are available beyond the bidirectional binding? unidirectional represent for this specific case a tricky solution. actually i thought to something MVC based.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting some point about your thoughts. You are asking something like in JSF, namely binding backing bean attributes to the front end components seamlessly. However IMO there is no the same functionality in JavaFX. You need bindable properties in model bean or manually synchronize through events like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you take a look at https://github.com/laubfall/modelfx. I wrote this library exactly for this reason. It supports bidirectional Bindings for JavaFX-Components (that are composed in a hierarchy) and Properties that resides in a Bean. For further Documentation refer to the Wiki-Pages of the Github-Project modelfx. Hope you find it helpful!

ps: the core functionality uses Bindings.bindBidrectional of JavaFX.