# JavaFX - how to add ChangeListener to TextArea binded with StringProperty from other class

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a main class where I have TextArea showing some logs of my program. It looks like this:

```
@FXML
private TextArea eventLog;
```

I need to access it from other classess (scenes), so it's binded with StringProperty like this:

```
eventLog.textProperty().bind(LogInfo.logDataProperty());
```

LogInfo looks like this:

```
public class LogInfo {

private static StringProperty logData = new SimpleStringProperty();

public static void setLogData(String data) {
        logData.set(getLogData() + data);
    }

}
```

setLogData is basicly copying all infomations already stored on TextArea eventLog and adding new line. It's working fine, but here comes my problem:

TextArea doesn't scroll when new informations are shown. I need to add ChangeListener to my eventLog textArea like this:

```
eventLog.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue,
                Object newValue) {
            eventLog.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE); 
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work, because informations are added by setLogData from LogInfo class, not from eventLog TextArea directly. So I need to implement ChangeListener on my LogInfo class, but the problem is that I can't control eventLog TextArea from LogInfo class. Is there any way to make something like reverse binding from this class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the listener directly to the `LogInfo` property instead of binding it to the `TextArea` property:

```
Main.logDataProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        });
```

Comment: If you'd like you could also add the listener to the `eventLog` as you initially planned but then instead of attaching `ChangeListener` you should use `InvalidationListener`. Also you should then change the binding method to `bindBidirectional`. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a bidirectional binding of you properties [see this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314863/javafx-bidirectional-binding-not-working-with-the-control-becoming-not-editable) for more information.